# Apache Cassandra Backup on linux

Tags: cassandra, database-backups

I have Apache Cassandra on linux OS.
What is the best solution for backup data from enviroment to antother enviroment without losing data

Answer (score 1):

[Medusa](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-medusa) is very good open source tool for backup of Cassandra.